# useState is not updating inside array.map(). ReactJS

Tags: arrays, reactjs, use-state

I am trying to add the values of an array by using useState inside an array.map but the values are not updating

```
function App() {
  const [ingredients, setIngredients] = useState([]);
  
  const getIngredients = (data) => {
    data.map((item, i) => {
      console.log(data[i]);
      setIngredients([...ingredients, data[i]]);
     // setIngredients([...ingredients, item]); <- Also doesnt work 
      console.log(ingredients);
    });
```

**Console.log(data)**

```
(26) ["Product", "Information↵NUTELLA", "HAZELNUT", "SPREAD", "↵Total:", "↵aty:", "↵BARILLA", "SPAGHETTI", "Z↵Total:", "↵CLASSICO", "CRMY", "ALFERO", "DI", "ROMA", "PENNE", "RIGATE", "PASTA", "↵Order", "Summary↵item", "Subtotat", "↵Sales", "Tax", "Total:", "", "↵", Array(0)]
```

**console.log(ingredients);**

> []

**console.log(items);**

```
Lists out all the items one after the other
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

setState is asynchronous so it doesn't guarantee an updated state from before, so pass a function to setState to make it work.

```
setIngredients((ingredients) => [...ingredients, data[i]]);
```

Comment: I didnt know about setState being asynchronous. Your solution worked, thank you.

Comment: hi can you please help me out. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73716653/how-to-add-a-new-element-inside-array-then-check-if-that-element-exists