# How to add a new element inside array then check if that element exists?

Tags: reactjs, chat

i have a get request that fetches data from my database to show on my website.

What i am trying to accomplish is when a new chat is created instead of refreshing the screen, i add it to the state set when the get request is completed.

when a new chat is created, it gets added to the list. Perfect

My problem is after the new chat is created and the user sends another message i am not able to find the new object added to the Array and so it also adds that the list and i get a error same id is used.

The problem occurs here:

```
if(records.some(e=>e['id']===msg.id)){
        console.log("id exists")
        var index = records.findIndex(x=>x.id===msg.id)
        console.log(index)
        let temp=[...records]
        const recordMessages=temp[index].Messages
        const newMessages=[msg,...recordMessages]
        temp[index].Messages=newMessages

        const lastMessage=temp[index].lastMessage
        const newLastMessage=msg.message;

        temp[index].lastMessage=newLastMessage;

        setRecords(temp) 
        }else{
            var index = records.findIndex(x=>x.id===msg.id)
            console.log(index)

            const newObject={
                id:msg.id,
                lastMessage:msg.message,
                admin:msg.receiverId,
                user:msg.senderId,
                updatedAt:new Date(),
                Messages:[msg]
            }
            const newRecord =records=>[newObject,...records]
            setRecords(newRecord) 
        }
```

```
if(records.some(e=>e['id']===msg.id)){
```

the error occurs in this line of as it is not getting executed

also, here is my api call:

```
            .get('/api/messages/',{headers:{"auth-token":localStorage.getItem('jwtToken')}})
                .then(res => {
                    setRecords(res.data)
                    // console.log(records)
                })
                .catch(err =>
                    console.log(err)      
                )
```

Answer (score 0):

`if(records.some(e=>e['id']===msg.id)){`

This is checking if the string 'id' is in the array. You want to pass in the variable id, which would be: `if(records.some(e=>e.id === msg.id)){`

Comment: i have tried both ways and both do not work